# Laravel, Submitting GET form doesn't trigger route

Tags: php, laravel, get

So i have a very strange problem occurring at the moment where i have a form that that submits as POST and triggers the route fine, whereas if the the form submits as GET it does not get triggered. It is just the strangest thing, in its simplified form the code looks like:

**Works**

route

```
route::post('/contributions/finalise', [ 'as' => 'contributions.finalise', 'uses' => function() {
    dd('i get output');
}]);
```

form

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'contributions.finalise', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

    {!! Form::input('hidden','amount', null, ['id' => "contribute-amount"]) !!}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Doesn't work**

route

```
route::get('/contributions/finalise', [ 'as' => 'contributions.finalise', 'uses' => function() {
    dd('i DON'T get output, only a white screen is shown.');
}]);
```

form

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'contributions.finalise', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}

    {!! Form::input('hidden','amount', null, ['id' => "contribute-amount"]) !!}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

As you can see they are very similar but the GET just doesn't work? Am i missing something really basic here?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

What error show for your post request?
I think this will be problem of CSRF Token. Add CSRF Token filed at your form.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'contributions.finalise', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    // Add CSRF Field
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    {!! Form::input('hidden','amount', null, ['id' => "contribute-amount"]) !!}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: the CSRF token is automatically added when you use the Form::open syntax so that is not the issue. Absolutely no error is output just a blank white screen with nothing.

Posting works without any issues, its the GET that doesnt work

Comment: Check error from laravel.log file `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Nothing related in there, like i said according to larval an error is not occuring

Answer (score 0):

So turns out there was a conflicting route that i didn't notice as the contribution was also a resource so it had a whole bunch of routes that i wasn't using.